# framer-motion animation happens on every re-render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I'm having some trouble with React and framer-motion.
I have a page that has 2 text field with states for their inputs.
In addition I have a chip list that I want to animate when a chip is being created (rendered).
The code to the page:

```
import { Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import FieldInput from "../../components/FieldInput/FieldInput";
import FieldTitle from "../../components/FieldTitle/FieldTitle";
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import ChipsList from "../../components/ChipsList/ChipsList";

const UploadPage = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [artistsInput, setArtistsInput] = useState("");
  const [artistsList, setArtistsList] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleNameChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleArtistsChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setArtistsInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleAddArtist = () => {
    if (
      artistsInput === "" ||
      artistsList
        .map((artist) => artist.toLocaleLowerCase())
        .includes(artistsInput.toLocaleLowerCase())
    )
      return;
    setArtistsList((prevArtistsList) => [...prevArtistsList, artistsInput]);
    setArtistsInput("");
  };

  const handleDeleteArtist = (artistToDelete: string) => {
    setArtistsList((prevArtistsList) =>
      prevArtistsList.filter((artist) => artist !== artistToDelete)
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h1">
          Upload a New Piece
        </Typography>
        <FieldInput
          title="Name"
          handleUserInputChange={handleNameChange}
          userInput={name}
        />
        <FieldInput
          title="Artists"
          handleUserInputChange={handleArtistsChange}
          userInput={artistsInput}
          additionalInformation="An artist that created, performed, or produced this musical piece. Press enter, or press the plus button to add more artists."
          handleAddClick={handleAddArtist}
        />

        <ChipsList list={artistsList} handleDeleteChip={handleDeleteArtist} />

        <FieldTitle title="Media" />
        <FieldTitle title="Tabs" />

      </Stack>
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadPage;
```

The problem that I encounter is every time I change the text field's value (and the state value changes), React re-renders the page's component and every of his son's component including the `<ChipList />` component (because for some reason that's how React works) and the animation triggers.

Here is the `<ChipList />` code:

```
import { Chip, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

type ChipsListProps = {
  list: string[];
  handleDeleteChip?: (elementToDelete: string) => void;
};

const ChipsList = ({ list, handleDeleteChip }: ChipsListProps) => {
  const MotionChip = motion(Chip);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid maxWidth="40%" container spacing={1}>
        <AnimatePresence>
          {list.map((listElement) => (
            <Grid item key={listElement}>
              <MotionChip
                key={listElement}
                initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                transition={{ duration: 1 }}
                label={listElement}
                onDelete={
                  handleDeleteChip && (() => handleDeleteChip(listElement))
                }
              />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default ChipsList;
```

I tried adding `<AnimatePresence>` thinking it might work.
I also tried to move `const MotionChip = motion(Chip);` outside of the component.

Thank you for your time, have a nice day!

Comment: To avoid unnecessary re-rendering cause by parent component, you could try if memo() can help or not : https://react.dev/reference/react/memo